# unexpected layout with DOCTYPE

Tags: html, css, scroll, doctype

I have a strange behaviour I cannot explain: the scrollbar for my page is not around the tag "main" as expected when I put the line `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of my code. If I remove this first line, I have the expected behavior. Why is that? What is my mistake here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Off Track</title>
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0px; padding:0px;">
    <header style="background:green; width:100%; height: 50px;">
    </header>
    <main style="background:red; width:100%; height:calc(100% - 70px); overflow-y: auto">
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
    </main>
    <footer style="background: yellow; width:100%; height:20px;">
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

NB : I also have the expected behavior if I replace `height:calc(100% - 70px)` by `height:calc(100vh - 70px)`, but I want to avoid using `vh`.

Comment: You have two different problems ("100% not working" and "different rendering with different doctypes") here. The two duplicates (linked) cover each question separately.

Comment: You need to have only one html tag and keep specific height if you know, that should solve your problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` line has nothing to do with it.

To get scrollbars only on your `main` element, you need to set `height: 100%` for its parent elements `body` and `html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" style="height: 100%;">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Off Track</title>
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0px; padding:0px; height: 100%;">
    <header style="background:green; width:100%; height: 50px;">
    </header>
    <main style="background:red; width:100%; height:calc(100% - 70px); overflow-y: auto">
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
      bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>    bla bla <br>
    </main>
    <footer style="background: yellow; width:100%; height:20px;">
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: what did I get that downvote for - did you even look at the code and the result?

Comment: I am not the one downvoted you... Your solution works for me, thank you!

Comment: To say that "The <!DOCTYPE html> line has nothing to do with it. " is a stretch. Without in place, quirks mode will cause the body to be 100% of the viewport high, hence setting height: 100% to the html and body elements is unnecessary. See [the quirks mode standard, points 3.6 and 3.7](https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-html-element-fills-the-viewport-quirk)

Comment: so why didn't that work obviously, and why does it work then when adding the 100% height for html and body?

Comment: It did work. "If I remove this first line, I have the expected behavior." Removing the line causes quirks mode.

Comment: but he didn't want to remove it...